# how to check and disable a menuitem in xul

Tags: javascript

The following is the code I'm trying to use to make a menu item checked and disabled. It is just disabled as it is changing the attribute to disabled from checked. But I want the element to be checked and disabled at the same time. How do I do that?

```
var tabsHereMenuItem = this.window.document.getElementById("monocleHookNewTabSelect");

if ( this.service.getNewTabWindowId() == this.getId() ) {
 tabsHereMenuItem.setAttribute("checked", "true");
 tabsHereMenuItem.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
}
```

Comment: can you post your complete code and probably fiddle

Comment: the element 'monocleHookTabSelect' is a menu item of type checkbox.I want the menu item to be checked and disabled.Could you please help me with this??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check and disable at page load, use below code inside `$(document).ready`.

```
$('#monocleHookNewTabSelect').attr('checked','true');

$('#monocleHookNewTabSelect').attr('disabled','true');
```

Here is the [**Fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/44H6k/)

Comment: you can even use $('#monocleHookNewTabSelect').attr('checked', 'disabled','true')

Comment: My code works in Firefox 31.0 in windows OS but not in Unix.The check is not happening when the menu item gets disabled in Unix OS.This looks wierd to me.Can you explain the reason by any chance??